# How to remove borders around a div (nav, footer, whatsoever) in a WordPress theme?

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I'm building this [Online Shop](http://shop.handmade-worldtour.com) right now, and I need to remove those two borders which surround the navigation. I already tried changing the color to white in the themes options, but then all the other borders throughout the page would change the color as well. So the easiest way would be to just remove them, but I really don't know how to remove them.

Any suggestions? I can't even find the classname of the mentioned border.

I can easily add custom CSS to the theme via the backend.

Comment: Actually, instead of asking us to overlook rule violations, I would encourage you to read the rules in the help center. You will find your stackOverflow experience much more pleasant that way, plus you will earn a nifty badge!

Comment: I was a first-poster too not to long ago. Keep trying and improving - and coding! :)

Comment: I agree. The people helping you are doing their best, so should you by reading the rules. Though I understand it can be a little scary at first.

Comment: Are you familiar with developer tools in chrome (press f-12) or firebug for firefox? These tools are indispensable when it comes to debugging css. It will show you what classes are applied to each element. You will also be able to experiment with CSS changes in the browser itself. For your problem look at writing a more specific CSS rule for your nav. Read up on CSS specificity and look at your nav to see what makes it uniuqe. I'm not going to an off site resource to debug your entire page. Perhaps provide a pared down version here. Just enough to view the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the following class :

```
#nav {
   border: none;
}
```

This will only affect your navigation while maintaining any border's applied anywhere else on the page.

In case you wish to add a different border to your navigation (which does not affect any other elements on the page), you can make modify the aforementioned code as follows :

```
#nav {
   border: 1px solid green;
}
```

You can add this to your custom CSS file.

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your theme all the borders have the same color, try to dissociate borders' styles, take this part appart.
You need to find the place in the CSS file

```
//change the color (line 22 and 40)
#header.skin3 #nav {
    border-bottom-color: #C38D67;
    border-top-color: #C38D67;
}

// or remove borders (line 1095)
#header.skin3 #nav {
    border-top: none;
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

**Developper tool in Firefox :** I used the developper tool in firefox to select the nav, it returns the CSS (including borders then) that is linked with the div nav, this makes it easier to find the right place in the CSS file (line 22 and 40 in your case). The same exists in chrome, and in other browser i'm sure and it's very usefull.

Answer (score 0):

I found this in style.css

```
#header.skin3 #nav{
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
padding: 10px;
border-top: 1px solid;
border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
```

you have a top and bottom border on your nav bar so if you just removed the top and bottom border the lines surrounding the nav bar will disappear